# Is there a strict store sequence of function arguments in registers r0-r4 in ARM assembly for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: assembly, arm

In ARM assembly code on Raspberry Pi, can we use register r1 (instead of register r0) for receiving the first function parameter while keeping register r0 only for the returned value of the function? Or must the first 4 function parameters be stored, sequentially and strictly, in the registers r0, r1, r2 and r3?

Comment: If it's your own code, you can do whatever you want. If you want to interoperate with 3rd party code, you must adhere to the convention obviously. How would the caller know that you expect the arguments in a different place?

Comment: You *could* just have the function take an unused first argument (dummy argument). Not elegant, but it won't break the platform ABI.

Comment: The called routine must save `r0` if it needs the input parameter while formulating the output `r0`.  Often this is not the case.  Another way is to use a 'callee saved' register (R4-R10) to keep the return value and then put it in `r0` just before return.  Even if it is your own code, for sanity reasons it is good to stick to a standard, especially if the routine is externally callable.  If it is an assembler helper function then for efficiency reason you could ignore the ABI.  You need to document the interface well if you don't use the ABI.  ABI mix ups can create difficult to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if your code have to be used/called from other code. There are some "rules" on how the registers shall be used, how the parameters shall be pass betweeen calls etc. These rules are called ABI (Application Binary Interface) and for ARM can be found here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html

That allows to call code written in "C" to code written in (for example) Assembler or other languages, that is part of the magic behind shared libraries.

If you are programming your Raspberry as a bare metal piece of HW, that is, you are not doing SW that shall interface with the operating system nor other applications, you can write code on your way, but in general you should follow these rules when programming in assembler. Even if you do not plan to work with other SW components or OS.  That will make simpler to port your code.